# dojo.place how to pass parameter without surrounding HTML?

Tags: dojo

I'd like to do something like this:

```
dojo.place(this.message.subject, this.apSubject);
```

But it throw exception in Dojo 1.7 (I'm completely new to Dojo so I don't know if the same problem is under older versions)

To get it work I did:

```
dojo.place('<span>' + this.message.subject + '</span>', this.apSubject);
```

It looks like Dojo parse the first parameter of `dojo.place` and if there is no HTML it throw exception.

How to use it without spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/place.html), In particular, the description of what the first argument receives:

> dojo.place(node, refNode, pos)
>
> node
>
> Can be a String or a DOM node. If it is a string starting with “<”, it is assumed to be an HTML fragment, which will be created. Otherwise it is assumed to be an id of a DOM node.

Therefore, one things you can do is create a text node with the text you want

```
dojo.place( document.createTextNode(this.message.subject), this.apSubject)
```

And another thing you could try would be setting the innerHTML instead of using dojo.place:

```
this.apSubject.innerHTML = this.message.subject;
```

---

BTW, In my humble opinion, dojo.place is normaly kind of annoying to use. However, since I am not often doing this kind of DOM manipulation, I don't really know what are the alternatives people prefer to use.